# Using CSort in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am confused as to how to use CSort in Yii for a drag and drop user interface that will change the sorting of item.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
  $item = JSON::Decode($_POST['sortItems']); // array(1=>2,2=>3,3=>1);

  $sort=new CSort;
  $sort->modelClass='Item';
  $sort->attributes=array('sort_order');
  //$sort->attributes = $item;

  $sort->applyOrder(); //$criteria
```

How do I get the item sorting (array) into the CSort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSort` is meant to read the requested sorting criteria straight from `$_GET` parameters; you are supposed to put them there by using [`CSort::link`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) to generate URLs that describe any desired sorting. Typically you would create a `CSort` instance, use it to fetch the data and immediately afterwards also use it to output links to the same controller action that when clicked cause `CSort` to change the sort order.

If you want to manually specify the sort criteria then `CSort` is not the right tool for the job. Practically however, there's a good chance that you should either:

- change the URL generation to also be handled by `CSort` as described above
- use a built-in data display widget such as [`CGridView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) instead of writing manual code

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction and I handled this problem differently.